# How to pass a file to backend api in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a small React App in which I read the email and file from the user and send it to back end api. (I want the user to upload just one file not multiple)

```
class App extends Component{
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state={
            email:"",
            file:null
        };
        this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
        this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
        this.handleFile = this.handleFile.bind(this);
    }
    handleChange=(event) => {       
        this.setState({
           email: event.target.value
        })
        console.log(this.state)
    }
    handleFile=(event) => {       
        this.setState({
            file: event.target.files[0]
        })

    }
    handleSubmit= (event) =>{

        const data = new FormData();
        data.append('file', this.state.file);
        data.append('email', this.state.email);
        axios.post('/files', data).then((response) => {
          console.log(response); 
        })

        console.log(data); //returns null 
        console.log("form submit")
        console.log(this.state)
    }

    render(){

        return(

            <div>
                <form>
                    <label> Email : </label>
                    <input name="email" type="text" onChange = {this.handleChange}/>

                    <label> Upload File : </label>
                    <input name="file" type="file" onChange={this.handleFile}/>
                    <button type="submit" onClick={this.handleSubmit}>Submit</button>

                </form>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
export default App;
```

The issue I'm facing is that the formData returns null. So, when I print the `data` it gives me null values but I can see that the state values are being updated. Why is that happening?

Comment: I tried the loop for console log but it sends Null values

Comment: Alright then, what happens when you do `console.log(Array.from(data.entries()));`?

Comment: Got the values now! I was entering the wrong values, my bad! Thanks